# Node.js + Angular 2 RxJS Observabes & Change Detection - Best way to utilize Ajax Service with REST API?

Tags: ajax, rest, angular, observablecollection, angular2-services

I am very new to Angular 2 and do not know much about RxJS or the nature of observables. I am trying to achieve a certain functionality however, and am just looking for a guide to the right information I should be learning to achieve this and a more thorough knowledge.

I am working on a basic web application which is more of a test than anything, where several of my Angular 2 routed views will need to be asynchronously getting data from a REST API endpoint I built in Node.js.

Here is what I am trying to achieve:

When I route (with Angular) to `site.com/messages` there will be a view, whose component will be utilizing a service which is pulled in through a parent component's providers array. I need this service to constantly get data from the API endpoint `site.com/api/messages`.

It seems to me that the most intuitive way to do this would be to have the the component that needs the data setup an `http.get()` on `setInterval()` when the component is initialized (`ngOnInit` life cycle hook). This will repeatedly poll the endpoint I need, so that it gets the data for the view which can use a structural directive to iterate through it or something like that.

Issue with this is I feel that it is a very primitive way to handle getting data. I would like to be using the newest and most effective and efficient way to do this. Unfortunately I am very new to Angular 2 and am not very familiar with some of the technologies and practices behind it. I have heard of and seen RxJS observables, Angular change detection, RxJS observable streams, and am wondering what the best way to learning these and what exactly will they buy me as far as asynchronous data fetching with an Angular 2 service. Any information as to how to utilize these technologies and how they all fit together would be great. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the interval method of the Observable class. For example:

```
constructor() {
  initializePolling().subscribe(
    (data) => {
      this.dataToDisplay = data;
    }
  );
}

initializePolling() {
  return Observable
     .interval(60000)
     .flatMap(() => this.getNewMessages());
}
```

You can then use dataToDisplay in the component template directly.

You can also leverage the async pipe to display an observable:

```
constructor() {
  this.dataToDisplay = initializePolling();
}
```

And in the template for example:

```
<div *ngFor="d of dataToDisplay | async">{{d.someProperty}}</div>
```

Comment: Thanks very much. I'll be looking into this. Also, is there any way to get that constant stream of data without sending HTTP request after HTTP request to the API without using socket.io? I've debated learning it and still might, but I just want the know more about the ways of approaching this. Thanks

Comment: Basically is this the best way to go about managing a lot of realtime communication and data?

Comment: Is the method you laid out similar to the one mentioned here https://github.com/ng-book/angular2-rxjs-chat ?